# Mixed up over spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, spherical-coordinates

So messing about with spherical coordinates, I wanted at some point to get the expressions for $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial x }{\partial r}$; using the convention:

$$ \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c} 
   x = r \text{ cos} \theta \text{ sin} \phi \\
   y = r \text{ sin} \theta \text{ sin} \phi \\
   z = r \text{ cos} \phi. \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

For $\frac{\partial x }{\partial r}$ I do:

$$ \frac{\partial{} }{\partial r} [r \text{ cos} \theta \text{ sin} \phi]
   = \text{ cos} \theta \text{ sin} \phi. $$

For $\frac{\partial r }{\partial x}$, I use:

$$ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 $$
$$ \rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [r^2] = 2 r \frac{\partial r }{\partial x} = 2 x $$
$$ \rightarrow \frac{\partial r }{\partial x} = \frac{x}{r} = \frac{r \text{ cos} \theta \text{ sin} \phi}{r} = \text{ cos} \theta \text{ sin} \phi. $$

How come I get the same for both?

Comment: Isn't $x = r \cos \theta \sin \phi$?

Comment: I measured $\theta$ from the x axis toward the y axis (like in the polar coordinates), and $\phi$ from the xy plane toward the position vector - comparing with the book I see they swap around $\phi$ and $\theta$ but they are just labels for the same thing as far as I can see

Comment: I urge you to use traditional notation, so that the limits are traditional as well.  (The traditional limits on $\phi$ and $\theta$ are of course not the same.

Comment: I.e. I get $\text{ cos} \phi}$ because I measure $\phi$ from the "floor" instead of from the z-axis. But shouldn't it all add up anyways?

Comment: I'll edit the question to use traditional notation

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that you're using a non-standard definition of angles and then finding that you get a form of contradiction involving these angles for what should be a trivial pair of derivatives.  Few are likely to help you when you use non-standard definitions in such a case, feeling that there is some trivial switching of variables that solves everything—that you should find on your own.

Comment: I changed it to use $\phi$ as you mention - I've checked to make sure he convention agrees with the one used in Wikipedia. But I get the same problem, the logic I used to get there is the same

Comment: Thanks for staying up on this one, am I doing something that is fundamentally wrong? To me they each seem like reasonable steps...